# Find $U(P,f,\alpha)$ and $L(P,f,\alpha)$, where $f(x) = 1+x^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-sum

Given $f(x) = 1+x^2, \alpha(x) = x^3, x \in [-1,1], P = \{-1,\frac{-1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},1\}$. Find $U(P,f,\alpha)$ and $L(P,f,\alpha)$.

Ok, for this problem, we have $\alpha (x) = x^3$. And, I am confused where should I apply $\alpha(x) = x^3$. For the upper bound, I have use this: $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} f(xi)\Delta x$ and for lower bound I've used this: $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (f(xi)-\Delta x)\cdot \Delta x$. I know when $\alpha(x) = x, \Delta \alpha(x) = \Delta(x)$.  But, now that I have $\alpha(x) = x^3, \Delta \alpha(x) \neq \Delta x$. So, is $\Delta \alpha (x) = (1)^3 -(-1)^3 = 2$ in this case? And, what would be the formula for $\alpha (x)$? Any help? Thanks.

Comment: $\alpha(x)=x^3$ but you put it $\frac{1}{2}$ why ?

Comment: $$U(P,f, \alpha) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (1+(\frac{i^2}{4}))\cdot \Delta \alpha(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that given a partition $P=\{-1,\frac{-1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},1\}$ of $[-1,1]$ with $\alpha(x)=x^3$, then
\begin{align*}
U(P,f,\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^nM_i\cdot\Delta\alpha_i
\end{align*} 
where $M_i=\sup_{x_{i-1}\le x\le x_i}f(x)$ and $\Delta\alpha_i=\alpha(x_{i})-\alpha(x_{i-1})$. Now it's a matter of just plugging in.

I will work through the computation for you so you can see.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^4M_i\cdot\Delta\alpha_i&=f(-1)\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)+f\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)+f\left(1\right)\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)\\
&=2\cdot\frac{7}{8}+\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{8}+\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{8}+2\cdot\frac{7}{8}\\
&=\frac{61}{16}.
\end{align*}

Comment: It's not always as straightforward as plugging it into a formula. You will need to see what the supremum of $f(x)$ in each of the intervals is and use that for $M_i$.

Comment: I think I've got the idea. And, if you don't mind, here is my lower bound: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(\frac{-1}{2})\cdot \frac{7}{8}+f(0)\cdot (\frac{1}{8})+f(0)\cdot (\frac{1}{8})+f(\frac{1}{2})\cdot(\frac{7}{8}) = ...= \frac{11}{4}$. I just copied the $\Delta \alpha(x)$, since it is the same for both upper and lower bound, right?

Comment: $f(\frac{-1}{2})=\frac{5}{4}$ and thus $\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{7}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{7}{8}=\frac{39}{16}$. And yes, $\Delta\alpha_i$ is the same.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. Thanks once again for helping me understand this.